# Matching Src attributes that don't begin with HTTP

Tags: perl

I'm trying to match all `src` attributes that do not begin with `http`.

Comment: What are you talking about? Please show some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I selectively modify the src attributes of script tags in an HTML document using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252314/how-can-i-selectively-modify-the-src-attributes-of-script-tags-in-an-html-docume)

Answer (score 2):

That's not the "not" operator.  That's the "beginning of line" anchor character.

Something like `s!^(?!http)/?!$PATH_BLAH/!` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1: good call working out what the question meant!

Comment: On issue with this, that daxim's solution should handle, is protocol relative paths. For example if I have `<img src="//images.example.com/foo.png">` then if the page was served over http then the absolute URL should become `http://images.example.com/foo.png`. The same file served over https would result in `https://images.example.com/foo.png`. This can be absurdly useful if you pre-generate mostly static HTML that has to be served to both not logged in users (http) and logged in users (https to protect cookies).

Answer (score 2):

You want to resolve URIs to absolute URIs. Using a robust HTML parser:

```
use strictures;
use URI qw();
use Web::Query 'wq';

my $PATH_BLAH = 'http://example.com/blah/';
my $html = <<'HTML';
<html><head></head><body>
<img src="../relative-link" />
<img src="yup/another/one" />
<img src="/oh/I/start/with/a/slash" />
<img src="http://example.net/absolute-link" />
</body></html>
HTML

my $w = wq $html;
$w->find('*[src]')->each(sub {
    my (undef, $e) = @_;
    $e->attr('src', URI->new_abs($e->attr('src'), $PATH_BLAH));
});
print $w->html;

__END__
<html><head></head><body>
<img src="http://example.com/relative-link" />
<img src="http://example.com/blah/yup/another/one" />
<img src="http://example.com/blah/oh/I/start/with/a/slash" />
<img src="http://example.net/absolute-link" />
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not Perl. I'm guessing it's a regular expression? And I'm guessing you're trying to match characters that don't include "http"? If so, you want

```
(?:(?!http).)*
```

`(?:(?!STRING).)` is to `(?:STRING)` as `[^CHAR]` is to `CHAR`.