# How can I selectively modify the src attributes of script tags in an HTML document using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing, html-parser

I need to write a regular expression in Perl that will prefix all srcs with [perl]texthere[/perl], like such:

```
 <script src="[perl]texthere[/perl]/text"></script>
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247071

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper parser such as [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(handle => \*DATA);

while (my $token = $parser->get_token('script')) {
    if ($token->is_tag('script')
            and defined(my $src = $token->get_attr('src'))) {
            $src =~ m{^https?://}
                or  $token->set_attr('src', "[perl]texthere[/perl]$src");
    }
    print $token->as_is;
}

__DATA__
<script src="/js/text.text.js/"></script>

And at the same time, ignore scrs that begin with http, as such:

 <script src="https://websitewebsitewebsite"></script>
```

Output:

```
<script src="[perl]texthere[/perl]/js/text.text.js/"></script>

And at the same time, ignore scrs that begin with http, as such:

 <script src="https://websitewebsitewebsite"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the negative lookahead pattern (on the third line below):

```
s{
  (<script\s+src\s*=\s*[\'"])
  (?!https?://)
}{$1\[perl]texthere[/perl]}gsx;
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 13 seconds.  +1

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this. If I'm using find and replace in BBedit, what goes in the find and replace fields?

Comment: The syntax provided in the answers means `s{FIND}{REPLACE}`. Just try some variants. If it allows *lookaround* assertions, you could check `(?<=src=)(?!"https?)` in the find, and `[perl]texthere[/perl]` in the replace part. If not, we'll see ...

Answer (score 0):

I am able to match any src=" except for http via: `^<script src="(?!(https:)).*$`
Let me know if there are any issues and I'll fix it.

Try using: [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as a regex tutorial and [this website](http://regexpal.com) to test regex.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 s{(?<=src=)(?!"https?)}{[perl]texthere[/perl]}
```

Test:

```
 my @olnk = ('<script src=/js/text.text.js/"></script>',
             '<script src="https://websitewebsitewebsite"></script>' );
 my @nlnk = map {
                  s{(?<=src=)(?!"https?)}{[perl]texthere[/perl]}; $_
                } @olnk;
```

Result:

```
 print join "\n", @nlnk;

 <script src=[perl]texthere[/perl]/js/text.text.js/"></script>
 <script src="https://websitewebsitewebsite"></script>
```

Regards

rbo