# In Perl, how can I replace relative URLs in src attributes of img tags with absolute URLs?

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I want to find and replace (from an html page) all occurrences of `src` attributes in `img` tags. E.g., take

```
<img width="25" height="13" border="0" src="/images/flags/de.png">
```

and change the `src` attribute

I am currently using:

```
$info{content}=~s!(<img[^>]src=")(/.*)"!$http://$dest$2!gi;
```

where `$dest` is the URL I want to put.

My problem is that it finds the 1st occurrence and not the subsequent ones.

Isn't the `/g` option supposed to replace all occurrences?

I'm sure the regex works for the next occurrence, because if i add my code line another time, the next occurrence is replaced.

Comment: [Use a proper parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247071/trying-to-use-the-not-operator-in-perl-and-it-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-how-d (same topic, not exact duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt didn't work because the greedy `.*` in the middle of your pattern matched *everything* between the first `src=` and the last `"`.

Making it non-greedy `.*?` would help.

Comment: If, by *work*, you mean correctly replace all `src` attributes, chances are, it will still fail to do what you want in various specific situations.

Comment: I'm only using it for few html pages, and it's always coded the same way, so it would work. But using a parser is better

Answer (score 4):

You want to resolve URIs to absolute URIs. Using a robust HTML parser:

```
use strictures;
use URI qw();
use Web::Query qw();

my $dest = 'http://example.com/blah/';
my $html = '<img width="25" height="13" border="0" src="/images/flags/de.png">';

my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html($html);
$w->find('img[src]')->each(sub {
    my (undef, $i) = @_;
    $i->attr('src', URI->new_abs($i->attr('src'), $dest));
});
print $w->html;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a proper parser such as [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( ... );

while (my $token = $parser->get_token) {
    if ($token->is_start_tag('img')) {
        if (defined(my $src = $token->get_attr('src'))) {
            $token->set_attr(src => "$dest/$src");
        }
    }
    print $token->as_is;
}
```

Comment: I assure you, `/g` works. However, see [Alan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11310327/100754) for why `/g` does not do what you'd like it to do with your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $dest = 'http://example.com/blah/';
my $html = '<img width="25" height="13" border="0" src="/images/flags/de.png">';
$html =~ s!(?<=src=")(?=/)!$dest!;
print $html;
```